# How to check that a column values has string or digits values in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have mysql table with multiple columns, a column has **string data type** namely `code` and the values of the column might be digits only or mixed of string and digits e.g: one row value has `57677` and other rows column value like `2cskjf893` or `78732sdjfh`.

```
mysql> select * from testuser;
+------+--------------+
| id   | code         |
+------+--------------+
|    1 | 232          |
|    2 | adfksa121dfk |
|    3 | 12sdf        |
|    4 | dasd231      |
|    5 | 897          |
+------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table testuser;
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------    ---------------------------------------------------------------+
   | Table    | Create Table                                                                                                                        |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------    ---------------------------------------------------------------+
| testuser | CREATE TABLE `testuser` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------    ---------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I would like to filter out only rows which has numeric value in `code` column or filter rows which has string values in `code` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

Mysql Query to fetch only integer values from a particular column

```
SELECT column FROM TABLE where column NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' ;
```

Mysql Query to fetch only string values from a particular column

```
SELECT column FROM TABLE where  column REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' ;
```

Comment: You might want to edit your answer, and separate the comments from the code, or even place several code lines, and text lines.

Comment: @jothi `ISNUMERIC` is not defined in MySql, getting this error: `ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION backend.ISNUMERIC does not exist`, I am using following version of mysql: `innodb_version          | 5.6.26-74.0` `version                 | 5.6.26-74.0-log` got it from the query: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`

Comment: Yes, got the result, you check it here: https://gist.github.com/krishnaiitd/6373ad1281f76bb4ebbe32ef8946c73b#file-testusertable-L28

Answer (score 3):

To get digits

```
SELECT id,code 
FROM table_name
WHERE code REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

To get string values

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE code REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]+$'
```

Comment: For getting numeric rows, your query work fine, you can check the query output [here](https://gist.github.com/krishnaiitd/6373ad1281f76bb4ebbe32ef8946c73b#file-testusertable-L95), for string its getting empty, I got the result by apply `NOT` operator in numeric regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Use [regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE code REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

This will filter out column values with all digits.

Comment: YES, I got the result using regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions in mysql too.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `code` REGEXP '[0-9]';
```

Results will be the rows, where any number in the `code`  column.

Comment: No, your regular expression is not correct as per questions I have asked, check the output of your queries [here](https://gist.github.com/krishnaiitd/6373ad1281f76bb4ebbe32ef8946c73b#file-testusertable-L127)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select id,code from table_name where code NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

Or,

```
select id,code from table_name where code like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: First query: `select id,code from testuser where code REGEXP '^[0-9]*';` gives  the rows with values like `232` ,     `adfksa121dfk`, `12sdf`, `dasd231` `897`, I want to filter only the rows which has numeric values in `code` column or string value in `code` column, here the string examples are `12qwq`, `we121`, `2w2` etc.

Comment: Second query return empty: `mysql> select id,code from testuser where code like '%[^0-9]*%';
Empty set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: I think your regular expression is not filtering only numeric value, you can check the output of your queries here: https://gist.github.com/krishnaiitd/6373ad1281f76bb4ebbe32ef8946c73b#file-testusertable-L63 , I think it should `'^[0-9]+$'` for numeric rows.